# Combining the ISBLANK and Date function

Tags: conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

I have been searching through forums and can not figure out how to succesfully combine the two functions ISBLANK and a date function.

What I need to do is use this formula in google sheets for conditional formatting.

I would like to highlight any row red where the cell value for that row is BOTH blank in column I AND the date in column D is less than a week away. Separately the functions work, but I can not figure out how to combine these two:

1. =$D2

   =ISBLANK($I3)

Answer (score 2):

This works in Excel 2010. I'm not sure if it'll work in Google sheets.

1. Select the range for which you want conditional formatting.
2. Add conditional formatting using the following formula: (be sure to change the row from `1` to whatever the first row of your selected area is)

   `=AND($D1<TODAY()+7,ISBLANK($I1))`
3. Select whatever formatting condition you want (font color, fill color, etc.)

Comment: This worked great, and in google sheets. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked. You can click the check mark to the left to mark it as an answer so people searching know it's been solved.